# docx4j or Apache-POI: How to get paragraph IDs from docx file containing images and languages other than English?

Tags: apache-poi, docx4j

I want to get paragraph ids from .docx file. I am not able to  get ids when there is file with language other than english or an image.

I have tried to read paragraphs by docx4j and apache-poi as below. But unable to get paragraph Ids.

```
 List<CLMParagraph> clmParagraphs = new ArrayList<CLMParagraph>();

    List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = 
  document.getParagraphs();

    for (int i = 0; i < xmlfragmentlist.getLength(); i++) {



        Node node = xmlfragmentlist.item(i);

        CLMParagraph paragraph = new CLMParagraph();

        // do something for each node

        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

            Element e = (Element) node;

            if (e.hasAttribute("w14:paraId")) {

                paragraph.setParaId(e.getAttribute("w14:paraId"));

                paragraph.setParaText(paragraphs.get(i).getText());

                paragraph.setSentences(getParaSentences(document, paragraphs.get(i)));

                clmParagraphs.add(paragraph);

            }

        }

    }
```

I want to get paragraph ids for the images and text in other than english language.

Answer (score 0):

In docx4j, with paragraph object P p, it is just p.getParaId()

See further https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/docx4j-openxml-objects/src/main/java/org/docx4j/wml/P.java#L364

Whether there are images or LOTE is irrelevant.